# Windows Desktop Extensions - which version should I reference?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

Background: I'm having trouble getting my app's new version accepted by the Windows store. They say that it crashes on launch. The app runs fine even when installed from the appxbundle file on my computer.

So I'm thinking maybe this has to do with the Desktop Extensions (for the UWP) that I've added. Perhaps I'm referencing the wrong version of that assembly. If the app is targeting version 16299 but min version is 14393 - which assembly of the desktop extensions should I include in the References? 14393? 16299? Or both (and the one between them as well)?

I'm tagging this Centennial as well even though it's a UWP app (from a Xamarin.Forms solution) because I needed the OK by the Centennial team for the Desktop Extensions. Maybe it has to do with that.

Comment: I'm targeting 14393

Answer (score 1):

If your app does not have the `runFullTrust` capability then you do not need Centennial approval. The Desktop Extension SDK just provides access to APIs that aren't necessarily available on other device families, like Xbox.

Your app can use the 16299 Extension SDK and still run on a 14393 OS as long as you don't use any newer APIs or you have light-up code in your app to detect whether APIs are available or not. You can use [the `ApiInformation` APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) to detect whether certain WinRT APIs are available or not.

Comment: `LaunchFullTrustProcessForAppAsync` does need `runFullTrust` and I'm using that. So do you have any ideas why an app would run fine on my computer and `terminates at launch` when tested by MS? Runs fine on my compputer - even when installed from the appxbundle.

Comment: What OS version are you using? What process are you trying to launch?

Comment: Windows 10 16299. A simple Winforms process that I wrote. It's in the package.

Comment: Did you test on 14393? Are you using any APIs that don't exist on 14392?

Comment: No. My computers are all on 16299. But I verified that the method runs on 14393 (in fact, VS gave me an error when targeting below that because it's not included below that.)

Comment: It is possible you are missing framework dependencies in your appxmanifest. This may explain why it works on your machine (which I assume has VS and therefore all frameworks installed), but fails on the MS test machine which is completely clean. Can you share more details about the app package, like the appxmanifest, or the app package itself?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I mean that the method exists in 14393 (it doesn't before that).

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT How would I make the app include frameworks? (like the desktop extensions.)

Comment: It's not about the desktop extensions (those are present in the OS by default), it's about things like the VCLibs. For example if your package contains a mix of UWP and Win32 binaries you would need to reference separate VCLibs for each:<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.UWPDesktop" MinVersion="14.0.24217.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />
<PackageDependency Name="Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00" MinVersion="14.0.24123.0" Publisher="CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US" />

Comment: Those entries go into the appxmanifest, under the <Dependencies> tag.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Would that make the app crash at launch? Wouldn't it only crash when I call `LaunchFullTrustProcessForAppAsync`? (BTW if you don't add `@ispiro`, I don't get notified of your response.)

Comment: @ispiro It depends which framework you are missing. If you are missing one that is required by your UWP process then it would crash on launch. Keep in mind we are only speculating here, as you have not shared any details about your repro yet.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT It's a UWP app that was fine until I added the Desktop Extension stuff.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT Your comment about the references to frameworks helped. I found that somehow 2 references were added to the UWP app's references compared to the past (besides the one to desktop extensions) I'm checking the matter now.

Comment: I'd like to verify - are the Desktop Extensions dll's that exist on the target computer, or are they on the compiling computer, with no need to exist on the target computer?