# Are UWP Desktop Extensions a runtime framework or an SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp, win-universal-app

According to a reply by someone apparently from Microsoft [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49499902/939213) it seems it's an SDK and he says I can use the 16299 Desktop Extensions version for targeting a 14393 machine.

On the other hand, in Visual Studio, it's added as a reference, which seems to indicate that it's a runtime executable that exists on the target computer and therefore I would need to target either 16299 or 14393, but not both.

I think it's more likely that it *is* an SDK, because if not - we wouldn't be able to target multiple versions of Windows 10 with one app (unless every version of the OS contains the older "runtimes" as well). But I haven't been able to find any source saying this explicitly.

**So**: Do I need to target the version on the target machine, or can I target the latest version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an extension SDK to the Universal Windows Platform SDK. For your desktop extension SDK you want to pick the same version that you are using for your UWP SDK reference, e.g. if you are using Windows SDK 16299, use the desktop extension SDK 16299. Adding such a reference adds a reference to .winmd files, which contain the metadata for the API surface (those are not runtimes). There is only one UWP runtime on your machine (the one that came with the OS installation).

You can still use the 16299 SDK to build apps that target 14393. See this topic for versioning considerations, and the concepts of minversion, targetversion and version adaptive code:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version